# php: syntax error when changing from v7 to v5

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am putting my php creation on to a web hosting service. They support php, but use 5, and I made my program in v7.the only error i'm getting is a syntax error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/a9537925/public_html/V.4/www/login/index.php on line 46
```

The error is occurring at the line:

```
$token = create_token(login_info($email, $password)['user_id']);
```

The page's code is:

```
<?php
require '../../request_manager.php';
if (isset($post['submit']))
{
    $data_missing = array();
    if (empty($post['password']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'Password';
    }
    else
    {
        $password = trim($post['password']);
    }
    if (empty($post['email']))
    {
        $data_missing[] = 'email';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = trim($post['email']);
    }
    if (empty($data_missing))
    {
        require '../../mysql.php';
        require '../../login_manager.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login_info where primary_email = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($extraOutput = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "MySQL retrned extra values";
        }
        if (!mysqli_error($dbc) == "")
        {
            die("Error while qxecuting MySQL query");
        }
        if ($output == null)
        {
            die("The email or password was incorect");
        }
        if (verifyPassword($password, $output['password']))
        {
            $token = create_token(login_info($email, $password)['user_id']);
            die('
                <html>
                <body>
                    <form action="../main/index.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="' . $token . '">
                        <div id="manual" style="display: none;">
                            if your browser dose not suport automatic redirects, click <input type="submit" value="here">
                        </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
                <script>setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("manual").style = "" }, 3000);</script>
            </body>
            </html>
            ');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "The email or password was incorect";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The folowing data was not submited: ";
        foreach ($data_missing as $missing)
        {
            echo $missing . " ";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a href="../signup">Sign Up</a>
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="./" method="post">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="email" required>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the rest of the code for the site can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0JpQiCxOW6tZFY5Y1FaR1hDQmM).

Comment: You need to call `login_info($email, $password)` and assign to a variable separately then get the index from that new variable.

Comment: PHP 5.7 never was -- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php57

Comment: Your code is failing on many levels. Plus, there are too many unknowns.

Comment: @JonStirling can you put your comment into an answer, also why is this different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `login_info($email, $password)` and assign to a variable separately then get the index from that new variable.

The reason for this is that your version of PHP (which I guess is actually 5.3, which is old and dead so I'd recommend a better host) doesn't support function array dereferencing (the bit that allows you to access an array key against a function call, i.e. `()[]`) which was added in 5.4.0.